# Ruby's dynamic Inject method not working

Tags: ruby

In irb to checkout the working of inject method I wrote down simple code to print the count of numbers divisible by 3 but somehow that's malfunctioning:

```
[1,2,3,4].inject(0) do |count,value|
    if value % 3 == 0
       count = count + 1
    end
end
```

It is something minor but I am not getting a hold on it.

Comment: `inject` isn't the right tool for this job: `[1,2,3,4].select { |v| v % 3 == 0 }.length` for example.

Comment: Yeah you are right. It will be a sugar if we were like adding all the items in an array or some other operation. I was just checking how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), you need to return the memo-element on each iteration:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].inject(0) do |count, value|
  if value % 3 == 0
    count = count + 1
  end

  count
end
#=> 1
```

Or, if you prefer the one-line version:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].inject(0) { |c, v| c += 1 if v % 3 == 0; c }
#=> 1
```

---

Worth noting. In some cases, you can substitute [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) for [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), and avoid having to return the memo object, but since the return value of the latter is the original object passed in, it only works with objects passed by reference (i.e. not `Fixnum`s.)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each_with_object(0) { |v, c| c += 1 if v % 3 == 0 }
#=> 0
```

Comment: Yeah!. Just figured it out after I posted. Posted below too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out it was infact something minor. I didn't return the count at end of each loop so count was nil after first iteration since I didn't return it. Blunder!

```
[1,2,3,4].inject(0) do |count,value|
   if value % 3 == 0
     count = count + 1
   end
count
end
```